# Blur effect CSS3 Firefox(linux)

Tags: html, firefox, css, filter, effect

I'm trying to get a blur effect on my photogallery if the user is not registered.
I got it, but only for chrome. In my Firefox 14.0.1 (linux) I'm not able to get it working

My html template (I develop under django)

```
<h2> Gallerie</h2>
<ul class="galeria" id="imagenes">
{% for image in gallery %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a rel="prettyPhoto[gallery]" href="{{image.url}}">
            <img width="120px" height="120px" alt="{{image.comment}}" src="{{image.url}}"/>
        </a>        
    {% else %}
        <img class="blur" alt="{{image.comment}}" src="{{image.url}}"/>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My site.css

```
img.blur{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
    filter: grayscale(0.5) blur(10px);
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gecko does not support the `filter` property. It only works in IE (`filter`) and WebKit (`-webkit-filter`). To apply blur effects in Gecko-based browsers (like Firefox) you could make use of SVG Filters. [Here is a good explanation](http://css-plus.com/2010/05/how-to-add-a-gaussian-blur-effect-to-elements-within-firefox/) how to use SVG Filters for a gaussian blur. These SVG Filters only work in Gecko so you still need your old code for WebKit & IE.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do it without svg, but it seems that it's not possible :)

Answer (score 3):

This explanation worked better for me.

http://css-plus.com/2012/03/gaussian-blur/