# Firefox Background Blur 'Invalid Property Value'

Tags: css, firefox

I have a background blur I am applying to my site. This works fine on Chrome and Safari. However, on Firefox I get an error `Invalid Property Value` using the following CSS:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(6px);
-moz-filter: blur(6px);
-o-filter: blur(6px);
-ms-filter: blur(6px);
filter: blur(6px);
```

Is there a way to blur the background using this method that works on Firefox as well?

Comment: maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984759/blur-effect-css3-firefoxlinux) can you help.

Comment: `filter` will ship in FF34, november 2014 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter